# How to apply Single responsibilty on a Component class?

Tags: angular, typescript, solid-principles

My question is kinda simple.

Let's assume we have 2 components, and each component has its own form.

First component: **create-post.component.ts**

Second component: **edit-post.component.ts**

When you **create** a post, you simply fill the fields on that form and if everything is valid, you submit and create that post (in some inner array).

When you **edit** a post, you load the specific post object into the edit component and then you edit whatever you need and submit.

Now, according to **Single Responsibility**, we should indeed create a class for managing post creation and manage **Internal UI Logic** of that component (**edit-post.component.html**).

However, I've seen in many examples that the preferred pattern to manage that case is using **1 form** and in case of editing, they simply save a **boolean** which is set when an event is triggered to notify a specific listener for a changed route param.

If that route param is indeed changed, then there is an **If statement** to manage that specific logic (same logic implemented in the **edit-form.component.ts**).

Having events and listeners to handle a different purpose seems like a violation of Single responsibilty.

This example is quite simple. In more advanced cases it seems like we can get a spaghetti code very fast.

What is the correct way of implementing such case if I want to stick with the Single principle?

Comment: If you use one component for both actions (create or edit),  your final bundle size will be samller. So, i'll bypass the single responsibility and go with the reuse approach. P.S. for web applications, size does matter ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add my own thoughs about that question which in my opinion is very interesting.

> Disclaimer: The code below doesn't tent to be a pure representation of SOLID in Angular but at least get close up to Single Responsability & Open-Close principles.
> I am totally open to any constructive comment and it would be great to have a look into another approaches.

In spite of the size does matter in web applications, we could achieve the `single responsability` & `Open-close` principles whitout affecting too much our bundles size.

Following with the example suggested in the question, we could have an user-form.component.ts which just handles main/common logic such as a form group plus all validations.

```js
// user-form.component.ts
@Component({
 selector: 'app-user-form',
 template: `
  <form [formGroup]="userForm" (submit)="submit.next($event)">
   <label>Username</label>
   <input type="text" formControlName="username" />
   <label>Password</label>
   <input type="password" formControlName="password" />
   <!-- ... -->
   <button type="submit" > Save </button>
  </form>
 `
})
export class UserFormComponent {
  @Input() set user(user: User) {
   this.userForm.patchValue({...user})
  }

  @Output() submit = new EventEmitter<User>();

  userForm = new FormGroup({
   username: new FormControl('', [Validators.Required, UserNameValidator]),
   password: new FormControl('', [Validators.Required, PasswordValidator]
   // ...
  })
}
```

Then it doesn't matter is is wrapped by a `edit-user-dialog.component.ts` , `add-user.component.ts` etc each wrapper can then manage it in a different way.

ex:

```html
<app-user-form [user]="user" (submit)="edit($event)">
</app-user-form>
```

```html
<app-user-form (submit)="add($event)">
</app-user-form>
```

If we start from the point the `user` components are hosted in its own module i don't see the point that breaking down that form and its wrappers should increase too much the bundle sizing.

Open-Close

Soemtimes the requirements(design, use cases ...) force to make bigger the user-form.component.ts by adding flags for example the submit button with a different label.
We would have to avoid these flags whenver is possible.

Don't do:

```js
// user-form.component.ts
@Component({
 selector: 'app-user-form',
 template: `
  <form [formGroup]="userForm" (submit)="submit.next($event)">
   <label>Username</label>
   <input type="text" formControlName="username" />
   <label>Password</label>
   <input type="password" formControlName="password" />
   <!-- ... -->
   <button type="submit" > {{ mode === 'edit' ? 'Edit' : 'Add' }} </button>
  </form>
 `
})
export class UserFormComponent {
  @Input() set user(user: User) {
   this.userForm.patchValue({...user})
  }
  @Input() mode : 'edit' | 'add';
  @Output() submit = new EventEmitter<User>();

  userForm = new FormGroup({
   username: new FormControl('', [Validators.Required, UserNameValidator]),
   password: new FormControl('', [Validators.Required, PasswordValidator]
   // ...
  })
}
```

Do:

```js
// user-form.component.ts
@Component({
 selector: 'app-user-form',
 template: `
  <form [formGroup]="userForm" (submit)="submit.next($event)">
   <label>Username</label>
   <input type="text" formControlName="username" />
   <label>Password</label>
   <input type="password" formControlName="password" />
   <!-- ... -->
   <button type="submit" > {{ submitLabel }} </button>
  </form>
 `
})
export class UserFormComponent {
  @Input() set user(user: User) {
   this.userForm.patchValue({...user})
  }
  @Input() submitLabel = 'Save';
  @Output() submit = new EventEmitter<User>();

  userForm = new FormGroup({
   username: new FormControl('', [Validators.Required, UserNameValidator]),
   password: new FormControl('', [Validators.Required, PasswordValidator]
   // ...
  })
}
```

```html
<app-user-form [user]="user"
               [submitLabel]="'Edit'"
               (submit)="edit($event)">
</app-user-form>
```

```html
<app-user-form  [submitLabel]="'Add'"
                (submit)="add($event)">
</app-user-form>
```

That approach in particular allow us to provide a default translation, or use a custom one without touch the original user-form.component.ts

But there other cases, where the design or requirements are more expecific, then, we are forced to look for an elegant or complex solution. An example would be when in certain scenario we have to hidde an input or add an extra validation.

One approach would be break down user-form.component.ts in small pieces (form-field-component.ts) and project the content within the user-form.component.

```js
// user-form.component.ts
@Component({
 selector: 'app-user-form',
 template: `
  <form [formGroup]="userForm" (submit)="submit.next($event)">
   <ng-content></ng-content>
  </form>
 `
})
export class UserFormComponent implements IUserFormComponent {
  private value: User;
  @Input() set user(user: User) {
   this.value = user;
   this.userForm.patchValue({...user})
  }
  @Output() submit = new EventEmitter<User>();

  // IUserForm 
  userForm = new FormGroup({
   username: new FormControl('', [Validators.Required, UserNameValidator]),
   password: new FormControl('', [Validators.Required, PasswordValidator]
   // ...
  })

  
  reset() {
    this.user = this.value;
  }
}
```

```js
// user-form-n-field.component.ts
@Component({
 selector: 'app-user-n-field',
 template: `
  <label> {{ usernameLabel }} </label>
  <input [control]="control" />
 `
})
export class UserFormNFieldComponent {
  @Input() label = 'n'; 
  
  control: AbstractControl;
 
  constructor(userFormComponent: IUserFormComponent) {
    this.control = this.userFormComponent.userForm.controls.n;
    // maybe subscribe the userForm changes
    // or add extra validations
  }
}
```

The final usages could look like that:

```html
<app-user-form #form [user]="user" 
               (submit)="edit($event)">
 <!-- ... -->
 <app-user-form-avatar-field></app-user-form-avatar-field>
 <app-user-form-username-field></app-user-form-username-field>
 <app-user-form-password-field></app-user-form-password-field>
 <!-- ... -->
 <button type="button" (click)="form.reset()" >Reset</button>
 <button type="submit" >Edit</button>
</app-user-form>
```

```html
<app-user-form [user]="user"
               (submit)="add($event)">
 <app-user-form-username-field></app-user-form-username-field>
 <app-user-form-enabled-field></app-user-form-enabled-field>
 <!-- ... -->
 <button type="submit" >Add</button>
</app-user-form>
```